# RAILS twitter REST api upload image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, rest, twitter, upload

I  want upload an image & tweet from my app rails, I use this for tweet a message & image:

```
consumer = Twitter.connect
u_token = @aut_tw.token
u_secret = @aut_tw.secret
access_token = Authentication.twitter_prepare_access_token(consumer, u_token, u_secret)

response = access_token.request(:post, 
      'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update_with_media.json',
       feed.merge('media[]' => media, 'status' => @post.text_no_html))
```

but I get this error message: `195 missing or invalid url parameter`

Comment: From what I can tell, this does look like you are using this correctly, it should work. It's also now out of date, so for any other people who stumble over this same problem I suggest you stop trying to fix this problem and update.